# Is the specularity of a material a fraction of its total reflectance?

Tags: reflection

Specularity is a value that defines how glossy or matt a surface is. For example, a mirror is highly specular, but a brick wall is not. Is the specularity of a material a fraction of its total reflectance?

Comment: a radar maxim: at small enough grazing angles all reflections are specular...

Comment: @hyportnex hmmm..20 years in radar, never heard that. However, X-ray astronomy...I think so.

Comment: @JEB you've just mixed with the wrong crowd!

Comment: I did interferometric SAR imaging/mapping, so grazes weren't a thing. That and Mars surface modeling--no one grazes Gusev Crater.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily.  Assume I have light incident on a very good mirror, then depending on the spectrum of light, polarization, angle of incidence, some of the light might be absorbed.  So, the total amount of light reflected might be <100% of the incidence light.

Next consider a roughened surface, like the brick, while the same parameters  will determine the amount of light reflected, it could be the case that the total amount of light is the same as the mirror case.  It's just that roughened surface case will distribute the scattered light over a large set of angles.